# How can I apply machine learning to automated melody generation?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I've been working for a while on an app that makes up melodies. Each melody is composed of several phrases (musical sentences, or 'sub-melodies').

Now, I want to improve on this:

1. The user can press a button to 'like' a melody.
2. The app saves the phrases (sequence of notes)  composing the melody to storage.
3. These stored phrases will be integrated into future melodies.

In particular, the app should not only use the verbatim phrases but apply attributes like the rhythm, pitch etc. to generate new melodies.

My question is: Which machine learning techniques can I apply to infer new melodies using the stored phrases?

Comment: Person voting to close - mind explaining why?

Comment: In close reasons of old, I would have looked to 'too localized'. This question can be asked project upon project "is this machine learning? how about this one? what about this one over here?" without providing anything that another person would find useful. The question shows no research (not a close reason, I know), but instead polls for people's opinions on if this is or is not without any show of criteria or understanding about what machine learning is. The question fails to show even the basic "did you read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) page" understanding.

Comment: There is no problem presented, beyond a lack of understanding.  What understanding is there is not shown. No reason of "why do I want to know?" or "what does it matter if it is or isn't?" Questions that can be answered with "yes/no" and then some filler for minimum answer length really don't make good questions.  Is it machine learning? Dunno - depends on how you define it.  And how you define such a broad subject is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @MichaelT That's a lot of good feedback, but after reading your response, if I put myself in the shoes of the OP I'm not quite sure how (if possible) to fix the question. Would you perhaps recommend changing it to something along the lines of "What machine learning algorithms could I use with this type of melody data?" or some such related question?

Comment: @JTrana possibly, though realize that this area is something that books can be written on... there are entire [workshops](https://sites.google.com/site/musicmachinelearning13/) about the topic. [Algorithmic composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_composition) is quite a large topic (I would suggest pursuing the 'external links' there). There are [lots](http://andersoland.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/mlreport.pdf) of [papers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.6082&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on the subject. The challenge would be to keep it not too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is. It's supervised machine learning, in that you use preexisting external expert judgments to try to deduce the essence of a pattern (in this case, "pretty melodies") and ultimately allow you to generate more of them autonomously. The fact that the metric you are optimizing (aesthetic judgment on music) is somewhat  unusual doesn't change that.